# How to I merge two shapes into one?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

So I'm currently trying to merge two shapes into one.. On the left side you can see what it currently looks like, and on the right hand side is what I want it to look like.. I could just resize the green rectangle and place it at the bottom right, but I don't want to do that. I want to "cut off" the rest of the square that's overlapping. How do I properly merge two shapes into one?

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Width="100"
               Height="100"
               Fill="Orange"/>

    <Rectangle Width="50"
               Height="50"
               Fill="Green" Margin="421,238,329,146"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Look up `CombinedGeometry`. Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-a-combined-geometry?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Canvas Width="100" Height="100" ClipToBounds="True">
    <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Orange"/>
    <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Green" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50" />
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Ah yes! `ClipToBounds="True"` That's the one, thank you!